# Emacs, Evil-Mode: Replace only in visual selection/visual block?

Tags: emacs, replace, selection, evil-mode

By default, `:s/[search-term]/[replace-term]` works on whole lines rather than on visual selections. For example, if you select between c and e, as such:

```
a b |c d e| f g
```

and do `:s/ //g`, the result is:

```
abcdefg
```

rather than

```
a b cde f g
```

Similarly, in a visual block selection:

```
a b |c d e| f g
0 1 |2 3 4| 5 6
```

`:s/ //g` yields

```
abcdefg
0123456
```

rather than

```
a b cde f g
0 1 234 5 6
```

Does anyone have a way to make evil-mode's `:s/` work only on the selection (preferably by default, or alternatively with a keyword like vim's `\%V`)?

(`:s/\%V //g` does not seem to work in this case; it leads to 0 matches.)

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Emacs' default `M-%` (`query-replace-regexp`) works on region but not on visual selection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do the replacement in a visual selection by specifying the range. `'<,'>` works on the first line to the last line of the selection, and `` `<,`> `` works on the first character to the last character. So in your first example of

```
a b |c d e| f g`,
```

using `` :`<,`>s/ //g `` will give you

```
a b cde f g
```

Unfortunately, Evil doesn't seem to currently support replacement in a Visual Block, so there's no easy way to do that replacement.

Comment: Thank you! After some follow-up, I've also found `(setq evil-ex-visual-char-range t)` to enable that by default.  Bummer about the visual block mode, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a package `evil-visual-replace` to accomplish replacement in blocks:

https://github.com/troyp/evil-visual-replace

It would be nice if the underlying logic were integrated with `evil`, so that pressing `:` with a visual block just worked, but it's better than nothing.